# searching a pag for links (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom

I know this question might be a bit more open ended than usually asked here but I was wondering what the best method is for collecting all links from a web page and then placing those values into a javascript object. Forgive me as I am not proficient in javascript.

And those who undoubtedly will flame me should know that I have "done my homework."

[homework](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0280__Document/Getalllinksonapage.htm)

Comment: code you have linked to looks good to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

... returns the link elements.  Or, if you want the actual urls, add this:

```
links = Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(el) {return el.href;});
```

Comment: cool, how do i put them into an object or an array/ best method to send to a server?

Comment: modified answer such that 'links' is an array of urls.  To send to server, use AJAX (a more detailed discussion of which is out of scope of this answer.)